# WARNING: duplicate document ids found in sphinx

Tags: php, search, indexing, centos, sphinx

I tried to create my sphinx index. While indexing it showing this kind of a warning

WARNING: duplicate document ids found and skipping the indexing also.

Why this is happening. How can I fix this issue?

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. Could it be duplicate document ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic requirement of Sphinx is that it requires unique integer Document ID's. More about how Sphinx handles duplicate ID's at indexing & searching can be found here:

http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/03/15/the-clone-wars-how-sphinx-handles-duplicates/